# Login page disappeared after disable the authentication

Tags: moodle

> In Moodle, I disabled Web services authentication & OAuth 2, and after
> I logged out I could not log in again and there is no login form as in
> the attached screenshot.
>
> Login page: [login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAI5K.png)

Comment: Have you tried enabling cookies? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61416?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop or tried another browser?